# Exceptions not showing up in Application Insights

Tags: asp.net, azure-application-insights

We've just installed Application Insights on our server.

Everything seems to be working fine, but exceptions thrown on the server is not showing up in the portal.

We're logging exceptions with our custom tool, but we wanted to be able to see them in AI too, especially the unhandled ones.

It's a plain installation of the AI agent, on a Windows Server 2012.

ApplicationInsigts.confg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings" schemaVersion="2014-05-30">
  <!-- 
    Learn more about Application Insights configuration with ApplicationInsights.config here: 
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=392530
  -->
  <TelemetryChannel>
    <DeveloperMode>false</DeveloperMode>
  </TelemetryChannel>
  <TelemetryModules>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Tracing.DiagnosticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTracking.TelemetryModules.WebRequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTracking.TelemetryModules.WebExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTracking.TelemetryModules.WebSessionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTracking.TelemetryModules.WebUserTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.RuntimeTelemetry.RemoteDependencyModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.RuntimeTelemetry" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.RuntimeTelemetry.ApmcModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.RuntimeTelemetry" />
  </TelemetryModules>
  <ContextInitializers>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Contexts.ComponentContextInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Contexts.DeviceContextInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AzureRoleEnvironmentContextInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" />
  </ContextInitializers>
  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Core.TimestampPropertyInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Contexts.NetBiosMachineNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Contexts.OperatingSystemTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Contexts.ProcessIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Contexts.ProcessNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Contexts.ThreadIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Contexts.ThreadLanguageTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.TelemetryInitializers.WebOperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.TelemetryInitializers.WebOperationIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" />
  </TelemetryInitializers>
  <InstrumentationKey>....</InstrumentationKey>
  <ResourceID>.....</ResourceID>
  <StatusMonitor>0.10.0-build23829</StatusMonitor>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a blog post that describes what is collected out of the box and what you need to do in other cases: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/12/12/application-insights-exception-telemetry.aspx

Comment: On the above link, Web API 2.x Option 1 did the trick for me.

Comment: Link mentioned above is dead. May be https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/application-insights-exception-telemetry/ is the similar page.

Answer (score 1):

AI will not see the exceptions that you may have handled in any global exception handlers. I suspect that may be contributing to what you find. If you do use global exception handlers, you could use  the TrackException from AI SDK in the handler, that will then send them to AI.

Comment: The only place we touch unhandled Exceptions is in the Application_Error method in the global.asax, but we only read it and log it.